# Вопрос про флаг `last` директивы `rewrite`

Tags: nginx

Ниже приведён пример из документации NGINX, но по-моему даже если не менять флаг с `last` на `break` никакой петли не будет, ведь преобразованный URI больше не даст совпадения с регуляркой, а значит будет просто выполнена директива `return`. Или я ошибаюсь?

---

> Если же эти директивы поместить в location “/download/”, то нужно
>   заменить флаг last на break, иначе nginx сделает 10 циклов и вернёт
>   ошибку 500:

```
location /download/ {
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 break;
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/audio/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.ra  break;
    return  403;
}
```

Источник: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: Конкретно в этом примере петли не будет — тут вы не ошибаетесь. Но на все запросы будет 403, а не ожидаемый файл

Comment: Дааа, я нашёл ошибку! Хе-хе